# Python script to delete all .csv files in directory doesn't work when error occors

Tags: python, csv

i have an script that deletes all csv files exept 2 types. I have one file that i can't delete and i tried to delete it but it just doesn't work, even to i am the admin. So my script needs to skip this File. But it prints the Error and stops running. Hope you can help me.

```
import os


try:
    for rootDir, subdir, files in os.walk("Z:"):
        for filenames in files:
            if filenames.endswith((".csv")) and not filenames.endswith(("LBL.csv")) and not             
            filenames.endswith(("Code.csv")):
                foundfiles = os.path.join(rootDir, filenames)
                os.remove(os.path.join(rootDir, filenames))
except Exception as e: 
   print(e)
```

Comment: You could put the `try/except` inside the loop, instead of vice versa.

Comment: Tried it but doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

At first you can split your filename and extension better with the function.
Try this below

```
import os

try:
    for root, subdir, files in os.walk("..."):
        for file in files:
            name, extension = os.path.splitext(file)
            if extension == ".csv" and name != "..." and name != "...":
                try:
                    found_file = os.path.join(root, file)
                    os.remove(found_file)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
except Exception as e: 
   print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks for the fast input. But your code @multimoehre deleted the 2 types that i want to keep. Code.csv or LBL.csv isn't the full name of these files, they just end like that. So a mix of my and your code was the solution. Thank you.

```
try:
    for root, subdir, files in os.walk("Z:"):
            for filenames in files:
                if filenames.endswith((".csv")) and not     
                filenames.endswith(("LBL.csv")) and not 
                filenames.endswith(("Code.csv")):
                    try:
                        oundfiles = os.path.join(root, filenames)
                        os.remove(os.path.join(root, filenames))
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
except Exception as e: 
   print(e)
```